# Post Error with Apollo Client While Creating a New User

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am running into a POST http://localhost:4000/ 400 (Bad Request) Error.

I am trying to create a new user with the following frontend.

```
const REGISTER_USER = gql`
    mutation Mutation(
        $createUser: CreateUserInput!
    ) {
        createUser(createUserInput: $createUserInput){
            email
            name
            token
            password
        }
    } 
`

const Register = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])

    function registerUserCallback() {
        console.log("Callback hit")
        registerUser()
    }

    const {onChange, onSubmit, values} = useForm(registerUserCallback, {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password:'',
        confirmPassword: '',
    })

    const [registerUser, {loading}] = useMutation(REGISTER_USER, {
        update(proxy, {data: {registerUser: userData}}) {
            context.login(userData)
            navigate('/Dashboard')
        },
        onError({graphQLErrors}) {
            setErrors(graphQLErrors)
            console.log("Error: " + graphQLErrors)
            console.log(graphQLErrors)
            
            
        },
        variables: {createUserInput: values}
    })
```

However, the grapQLErrors is not even being console.logged for some reason. When I run the Mutation via Apollo Studio it works. Any information would be great!

Edit: Network Tab Screenshot:[image]

Adding Code for my httpLink:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
})

const authLink = setContext((_, {headers}) => {
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') || ""
        }
    }
})
export const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Edit: createUser Mutation seems to be the issue. This is the Network response error: ["GraphQLError: Unknown argument "createUserInput" on field "Mutation.createUser".","

```
@Mutation((returns) => User)
    async createUser(@Arg('data') data:CreateUserInput, @Ctx() ctx: Context) {
        const oldUser = await ctx.prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { email: data.email}})
        if(oldUser) {
                    throw new ApolloError('A user is already registered with the email' + data.email, 'USER_ALREADY_EXISTS')
                }
        var encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10)
        const newUser = await ctx.prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                name: data.name,
                email: data.email,
                password: encryptedPassword
            }
        })
        return {token: jwt.sign(newUser, 'supersecret')}
    }
```

Here is a screen shot of my Preview in my Network...I really don't get it.

```
export class CreateUserInput {


    @Field((type) => String)
    name: string

    @Field((type) => String)
    email: string

    @Field((type) => String)
    password: string
```

[image]

Comment: Ideally, you would use the network tab of your browser console to see the response of the request. A 400 Error will usually not return any `graphqlErrors` but a network error. With the error you might figure out the problem or we can help you here :)

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the Network Tab. It looks like CreatHttplink might be the issue.

Comment: You should be able to click it and see a detailed info. Then there is a "response" tab within the detail, that should show you the JSON reponse.

Comment: Okay, added additional information, it looks like its my input within my mutation.

Comment: Included an additional screenshot.

Comment: Its says that I have an unknown argument in my createUserInput...

Comment: Got it to this point I think: message: "Variable \"$CreateUserInput\" of type \"CreateUserInput\" used in position expecting type \"CreateUserInput!\"."

Comment: You have to adopt the definition of your variable to include the `!` in: `mutation Mutation( $createUser: CreateUserInput!)`

Comment: Now the error change to "Variable \"$CreateUserInput\" of required type \"CreateUserInput!\" was not provided.""

Comment: Have you checked the createUserInput.values contain what is expected (specifically looking at the variables in the useMutation function)?